# Is there a simple input box in Cocoa?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Is there a built-in, simple, input box in Cocoa which is designed for retrieving a string (like there is in good ol' Visual Basic that I remember)?

I suppose I could design a tiny window to do that but would prefer to use a native equivalent (if such a thing exists; I can't find it if it does).

Thanks.

Comment: You mean just a dialog window with a title, explanation text and text input field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and get return Value from Cocoa Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387341/how-to-create-and-get-return-value-from-cocoa-dialog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like a dialog with a text field, you either need to create it yourself or [put an `NSTextField` into an `NSAlert`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7387395/400056) (note that the linked answer presents a *modal* dialog that will block all interaction with the rest of your application; if you don't want that, you need to [present it as a sheet on a window](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAlert/beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:)).

Answer (score 33):

Thank you DarkDust for pointing me in the right direction. I would never have searched for "accessory views" in NSAlerts (I was lacking the right terms to trick Google or SO into giving me the goods!). I also forgot to mention that I'm using Swift, so I've knocked up a quick translation:

```
func getString(title: String, question: String, defaultValue: String) -> String {
    let msg = NSAlert()
    msg.addButtonWithTitle("OK")      // 1st button
    msg.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")  // 2nd button
    msg.messageText = title
    msg.informativeText = question

    let txt = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 24))
    txt.stringValue = defaultValue

    msg.accessoryView = txt
    let response: NSModalResponse = msg.runModal()

    if (response == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
        return txt.stringValue
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely want to evaluate the return value of `runModal`: if the user enters some text but then presses _Cancel_ you don't want to use the value from the text field.

Comment: Indeed. After posting that I soon went on to add a cancel button (which my solution above conspicuously is lacking; I've edited it accordingly). In my case if I get back a zero-length string I'm taking that as a cancel event. Others may wish to handle it another way.

Comment: Add `msg.window.initialFirstResponder = txt` to focus text field.

Comment: What if we want to add a second textField?

Answer (score 6):

Updating for Swift 5. I always put reusable items like alerts in an app manager class. And I like to keep my closures as a typealias to better organize them and keep the arguments cleaner.

```
typealias promptResponseClosure = (_ strResponse:String, _ bResponse:Bool) -> Void

func promptForReply(_ strMsg:String, _ strInformative:String, vc:ViewController, completion:promptResponseClosure) {

        let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()

        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")      // 1st button
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")  // 2nd button
        alert.messageText = strMsg
        alert.informativeText = strInformative

        let txt = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 24))
        txt.stringValue = ""

        alert.accessoryView = txt
        let response: NSApplication.ModalResponse = alert.runModal()

        var bResponse = false
        if (response == NSApplication.ModalResponse.alertFirstButtonReturn) {
            bResponse = true
        }

        completion(txt.stringValue, bResponse)

    }
```

Then call it like so (I needed this for a git management part of my app):

```
myAppManager.promptForReply("Changes were added to the repo, do you want to commit them?", "If you are commiting, add your commit message below.", vc: self, completion: {(strCommitMsg:String, bResponse:Bool) in

    if bResponse {
         print(strCommitMsg)
    }
})
```